# What is the relationship between measured time series, sample spaces, random variables, experiment, and realizations

Tags: time-series, random-variable, sample

Based off of several posts I have read on this site, I wanted to confirm that the following understanding is correct:

Suppose I have a device that translates a physical process of interest into an analog voltage signal that is then converted into / acquired as a digitized signal; the analog voltage signal is sampled at a finite $T$ discrete points in time. This results in a vector of recorded values: e.g. $\vec x=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{T}\}$ where $x_i$ represents the amplitude of the analog signal at time $t=i$.

It is my understanding that one potentially valid interpretation of this data set is as follows:

1. The *underlying physical phenomenon* (that is ultimately used to generate the analog voltage signal) is my **sample space** $\Omega$.
2. The device that I am using that translates the *underlying physical phenomenon* into the analog voltage signal (i.e. 'useable information') is a **random variable** $X$.
3. The **experiment** that is being performed is the repeated sampling of the analog signal at $T$ different points in time.
4. Each sampled value $x_i$ is a **realization** $X(\omega)$ of some **event** $\omega \in \Omega$. (For simplicity, let us assume that the digitization process has absolute precision ...otherwise we would probaby have something like $x_i = X(\omega) + \text{rounding}$)

Is the above description accurate?